# Checking if textEdit is same as string resource

Tags: android, resources, android-edittext

I am trying to get my app to check that text that has been entered into a textEdit field is the same as a string resource on a button click, and if so display a toast or println out correct, if not println or toast to say incorrect:

Currently I have this, which brings up no errors in eclipse, but I get null pointer exception errors in LogCat after trying to run the app:

```
btnCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if(editText1.getText().toString().equals(R.string.correct)){
                    System.out.println("Correct");
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Incorrect");
                }
```

I know that it cannot be the right code, but don't have looked around and everything I find points to having multiple buttons for quiz apps etc which is not what I am trying to do

Thanks

EDIT: I have done as per other users examples but the app is still failing to load, this is the logcat output:

```
05-07 13:50:01.951: E/AndroidRuntime(32712): Process: com.example.nametest, PID: 32712
05-07 13:50:01.951: E/AndroidRuntime(32712): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.nametest/com.example.nametest.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-07 13:50:01.951: E/AndroidRuntime(32712):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
05-07 13:50:01.951: E/AndroidRuntime(32712):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
05-07 13:50:01.951: E/AndroidRuntime(32712):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
05-07 13:50:01.951: E/AndroidRuntime(32712):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
05-07 13:50:01.951: E/AndroidRuntime(32712):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-07 13:50:01.951: E/AndroidRuntime(32712):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
05-07 13:50:01.951: E/AndroidRuntime(32712):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
05-07 13:50:01.951: E/AndroidRuntime(32712):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-07 13:50:01.951: E/AndroidRuntime(32712):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-07 13:50:01.951: E/AndroidRuntime(32712):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
05-07 13:50:01.951: E/AndroidRuntime(32712):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
05-07 13:50:01.951: E/AndroidRuntime(32712):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-07 13:50:01.951: E/AndroidRuntime(32712): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-07 13:50:01.951: E/AndroidRuntime(32712):    at com.example.nametest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:47)
05-07 13:50:01.951: E/AndroidRuntime(32712):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
05-07 13:50:01.951: E/AndroidRuntime(32712):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
05-07 13:50:01.951: E/AndroidRuntime(32712):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
```

And line 47 is:

```
btnCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
```

And now I have the app loading thanks to the answers below, the app crashes when users click to check button. LogCat error points to the line:

```
if(editText1.getText().toString().equals(getString(R.string.correct)))
```

Comment: R.string.correct is int(resource id) ... search for how to get string from resource id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace:

```
R.string.correct
```

with:

```
getString(R.string.correct);
```

`R.string.correct`, `int`, is key to actual string resource.

Your activity has a `getString` which takes `int` and returns `String`.

Comment: Thanks, I have amended my code as per your suggestion, but the app still fails to load. I have edited my question to add the logcat error

Comment: Please ignore above comment - I have it working now, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 btnCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if(editText1.getText().toString().equals(getString(R.string.correct))){
            System.out.println("Correct");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Incorrect");
        }
```

} });

Answer (score 1):

Replace `R.string.correct` by `getResources().getString(R.color.title_color)`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

vipul's answer is correct. 
I just want to add that in general, you should keep in mind that Android resources are basically just Integer values and you have to call the right context functions to obtain the actual objects.
At the moment you are comparing a String to an Integer (that is, apples with bananas).

Comment: Thanks, I have amended my code as per vipul's suggestion, but the app still fails to load. I have edited my question to add the logcat error

Comment: Please ignore my last comment - I have it working now

Answer (score 0):

An other way is like ,You can define a text that you want to match in `android:tag`

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/edittest"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:tag="your_text" />
```

And match with the `Tag` value

```
btnCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if(editText1.getText().toString().equals(editText1.getTag().toString())){
                    System.out.println("Correct");
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Incorrect");
                }
```